# How to resolve ElementClickInterceptedException when element is obscured in Firefox, Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, microsoft-planner

I'm trying to automate the process of logging into Microsoft Planner using Selenium and Python and I'm getting stuck at the step after providing a password.

In Firefox, the error received is

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (1089,523) because another element  obscures it

I understand that there are multiple posts with this question and I have tried 5 approaches based on them. I see the error in Approach 1 and 3, while all the other approaches don't throw an excpetion, but also do not move the cursor Image of final result - doesn't click on 'Sign in'

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
# driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.maximize_window()

url = 'https://tasks.office.com/company_domain/group_id'
email_id = "email_id_registered_for_microsoft_planner"
password = "password"

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "i0116").send_keys(email_id)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "idSIButton9").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "i0118").send_keys(password)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

# Approach 1
# element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "idSIButton9")))
# element.click()

# Approach 2
# element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "idSIButton9")
# driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

# Approach 3
# WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idSIButton9"))).click()

# Approach 4
# actions = ActionChains(driver)
# actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB * 2)
# actions.perform()

# Approach 5
# element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')
# ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

I tried this with Chrome as well and get the same behavior (approach 1, 3 fail while all others don't report an error but don't do the job) but with a different error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I am using

- Firefox version 99.0.1, Chrome version 100.0.4896.127
- Python 3.8.10
- Selenium 4.1.3
- Geckodriver version 0.31.0, Chrome driver version 100.0.4896.127 (ff0d0695743e65305d7194f9bd309e5e1c824aa0-refs/branch-heads/4896_88@{#4})
- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: Can you please share the full ElementClickInterceptedException exception message. Which element is obscuring your target element? You should see the element which the selenium complains about will receive the click

Comment: Reduce the scope of your question from ElementClickInterceptedException/StaleElementReferenceException and Geckodriver/Chromedriver to a single usecase to recieve a canonical answer.

Comment: @ShivamMishra I've update the error message to show that.

Comment: @electech It's not only about the title. One question should be specific to a single error wrt one specific environment. It's almost impossible to address all the relevant scenarios of multiple Erroe/Browser/Browser Driver in a single answer.

Comment: for `approach 1, 3` are we saying that we are getting `ElementClickInterceptedException` and other approaches do not really show any error in the console? If so, in what cases are we getting `StaleElementReferenceException` ?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium, do you suggest splitting this into 2 problems - one for Firefox and one for Chrome?

Comment: @cruisepandey that is correct. Approach 2, 4, 5 show no errors on the console, but the cursor is still at the password prompt. Approach 1 and 3 fail with `ElementClickInterceptedException` in Firefox, and again, cursor is still at the password prompt. In Chrome, I get the `StaleElementReferenceException` for approach 1 and 3 (2, 4, 5 respond similar to what happens in Firefox) and the chrome Window closes out (unlike in Firefox).